# PHP RegEx to find image-tags and replace quotes

Tags: php, regex, image, replace, tags

I need a Php-RegEx to find all image-tags in a php-string and replace all quotes (like ") in image-tag object.

```
$mystring = '<p class="testclass">test tag with p</p><p><img src="test1.jpg" width="100" /></p><p><img src="test2.jpg" width="100" /></p>';
```

The result that I need is the following:

```
<p class="testclass">test tag with p</p><p><img src=:quot:test1.jpg:quot: width=:quot:100:quot: /></p><p><img src=:quot:test2.jpg:quot: width=:quot:100:quot: /></p>
```

I've tested the following code:

```
$rep_html = '<p class="testclass">test tag with p</p><p><img src="test1.jpg" width="100" /></p><p><img src="test2.jpg" width="100" /></p>';
$rep_html = preg_replace('#<img ([^"]) />#',":quot:", $rep_html);
```

or/and:

```
$rep_html = preg_replace('#<img ([\x22]) />#',":quot:", $rep_html);
```

... Unfortunately, the code does not work that way. The quotes are not formatted to :quote:.

I do not need Php "domDocument" with "loadHTML" ... Only Php RegEx ...

Maybe someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for

```
<(?!img)[^>]*>[^<]*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|"
```

Replace with

```
:quot:
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/mG7xT9/1) with `code generator` on the left giving you an escaped PHP version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following code:

```
$rep_html = '<p class="testclass">test tag with p</p><p><img src="test1.jpg" width="100" /></p><p><img src="test2.jpg" width="100" /></p>';
$rep_html = preg_replace('#<img ([^"]) />#',":quot:", $rep_html);
```

or/and:

```
$rep_html = preg_replace('#<img ([\x22]) />#',":quot:", $rep_html);
```

... Unfortunately, the code does not work that way. The quotes are not formatted to :quote:.

Comment: I edited your question and included the code, if that's ok!

Answer (score 0):

With less steps, you can use this pattern:

```
\G(?:(?!\A)|[^<]*+(?:<(?!img)[^>]*+>[^<]*+)*+<)[^">]*+\K"
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH6pQ9/1)

or you can use @OnlineCop pattern with the S modifier.